# How to create TWRP's data.info file by hand/after the backup?

Tags: backup, twrp

I have a device with a dead screen, and a partially dead eMMC (poor contact, sometimes reboots. Sometimes reboots very often.). I managed to create a 12gb backup of the data partition somehow, but after generating two of the eight backup archives' .sha2 hashes my phone rebooted. So I have the backups in full, but the data.info is unfinished and there aren't enough .sha2. The latter are simple in syntax, so I can create them with HashMyFiles (SHA256). But deciphering the data.info, or forcing TWRP to make it after the fact is beyond my skillset. Is there any way to accomplish this?

EDIT:
I solved my problem, and also understood that this question was incomplete. It seems that the data.info is complete (and likely was one of the first files made after the backup archives themselves) and making the .sha2 by hand is sufficient. My real problem, which I didn't elaborate, was that Titanium Backup wouldn't work with this backup using the "Extract from Nandroid backup" function, so I decided that the data.info file was the problem, because it was the only different file, when compared to older, successful backups of the data partition. But the real problem was that I messed up the path (I added the backup folder, which is named as a date, directly to /TWRP/BACKUPS , when I should've added the backup folder in literally any folder one folder deeper, say /TWRP/BACKUPS/I_just_spent_10_hours_fixing_a_5_second_problem/), and Titanium Backup was too unsophisticated to check for PEBCAKs. That's about it.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Considering the Q&A nature of this site, please try to fill the missing details and remove the answer from the question, then post your answer as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to answer the headline, there exist a little shell script [twrp_sign.sh](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3775129) for generating data.info and sha2 digest. you can open it with text editor and see how it works

data.info is just a string containing
archive_name
backup_size
file_count
backup_type

Note: only the .win* files are important, all other files can be safely deleted without data loss